# Can I instruct gdb to run commands in response to SIGTRAP?

Tags: linux, debugging, gdb

I'm debugging a reference leak in a GObject-based application. GObject has a simple built-in mechanism to help with such matters: you can set the `g_trap_object_ref` variable in gobject.c to the object that you care about, and then every ref or unref of that object will hit a breakpoint instruction (via `G_BREAKPOINT()`).

So sure enough, the program does get stopped, with gdb reporting:

```
Program received signal SIGTRAP, Trace/breakpoint trap.
g_object_ref (_object=0x65f090) at gobject.c:2606
2606      old_val = g_atomic_int_exchange_and_add ((int *)&object->ref_count, 1);
(gdb) _
```

which is a great start. Now, normally I'd script some commands to be run at a breakpoint I manually set using `commands 3` (for breakpoint 3, say). But the equivalent for `SIGTRAP`, namely `handle SIGTRAP`, doesn't give me the option of doing anything particularly interesting. Is there a good way to do this?

(I'm aware that there are other ways to debug reference leaks, such as setting watchpoints on the object's `ref_count` field, refdbg, scripting regular breakpoints on `g_object_ref()` and `g_object_unref()`. I'm about to go try of those now. I'm looking specifically for a way to script a response to `SIGTRAP`. It might come in useful in other situations, too, and I'd be surprised if gdb doesn't support this.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

GDB doesn't support it.

In general, attaching a command script to signal makes little sense -- your program could be receiving `SIGTRAP` in any number of places, and the command will not know whether a particular `SIGTRAP` came in in expected context or not.

Comment: Distressing, but I suppose not entirely unexpected.

Answer (score 5):

Do you want to show some values and continue execution of the program? In that case, just define a macro that displays the values you're interested in, continues execution and calls itself recursively:

```
 define c
 echo do stuff\n
 continue
 c
 end
```